# Show more items in dropdown menu

Tags: css, selectize.js

I use selectize for the dropdown function,

However, I can only show 5 items at a time,

How could I show  more items?

The problem is not on JS side,

Because when I set `maxOptions: 2` there are only 2 items.

Here's the demo page http://133.130.101.114:8000/portal/index.html#/pages/scrum_board

any idea?

[image]

Comment: Menu contains a lot of items, but has scroll. What is the expected result different than what you have?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried scrolling down the drop-down? There are many more options in there if only you scrolled.
[image: See the scrollbar to the right]

Edit: Now I understand you want to increase the height of the drop-down list. I've not used selectize before, but I guess if it has an even it fires after transforming the select box, you can add the following code to it:

```
jQuery('.selectize-dropdown-content').css('max-height','50%'); //or any specific height you want in px
```

or just put it in a timeout event callback on document ready:

```
jQuery(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery('.selectize-dropdown-content').css('max-height','50%');
    }, 100);
});
```

Another screenshot to show the taller drop-down content:

[image: Taller drop-down]

Comment: sure, but I want it show more than 5 items at once :D

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a somewhat hacky solution, since I've not used selectize before.

Comment: Please flag as selected answer if it solves your problem. Thanks